# Why are multiple files much faster to compile than the combined file?

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm currently in the process of reducing compile time of a project with heavy template usage. It does a lot of template metaprogramming with expression templates and a lot of variadic structures.

I took the slowest file to compile. This file took 352 seconds to compile. It is made of 10 test cases. For the sake of testing and finding the compile-time bottleneck, I **split it into 10 files** (1 test case per file) and the sum of compilation time of each file (not in parallel!) is 215 seconds. This is about **40% faster**! I did not expect this. Generally, if you put files together, you have a gain in compilation time since some headers are only include once and the compiler can make use of template memoization to avoid some instantiations, but I don't see why splitting the file would make so much of a difference.

What could cause this large difference ?

I'm using g++-4.9.3 and this a debug build (-g only).

P.S. It also takes much less maximum memory, but that was expected.

Comment: How much max RAM did your monolithic build use, and how much does the build machine have?

Comment: Perhaps there is more optimization possible (and hence performed) when all sources are visible to the compiler?

Comment: @Mat The monolithic build took 4.5GB while the maximum of the 10 split files was only 3.5GB. The build machine used for these results have 12GB of RAM.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider It could be, but I don't see how in my case since it is 10 different test cases and they all see the complete set of headers. The source files are only tests, no other code inside.

Comment: Well, apparently they all get linked together into an executable or library? One way to check whether optimization kicks in negatively is is to simply prevent it by compiling with `-O0`.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I forgot to mention that this is a debug build (-g only).

Comment: Hm. I am not sure whether -g implies -O0. The docs mention that -g can be used together with -O which seems to indicate that absent -O no optimization takes place, for example no -fwhole-program or -lto or whatever. Well, it was an idea :-).

Comment: For a program that relies heavily on template metaprogramming, this doesn't sound particularly extreme. Template metaprograms are programs and can run for arbitrarily long time.

Comment: I checked again and I can confirm that it is -g -O0 build. @n.m. I agree that this would not be dramatic in terms of time, but the fact that multiple files are much faster is weird nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem, but I don't understand it exactly.

It was related to std::async and futures. I was using std::async to run some computation in parallel and the functor passed to it was kind of complex. Once I replaced the use of std::async and futures by my own thread pool, it reduced the compilation time of the monolihtic file **from 344 seconds to 44 second**s, this is almost of factor of 8. Moreover, now the split files are two times slower to compile than the monolithic file (84 seconds), which makes more sense.

The commit can be found [on Github](https://github.com/wichtounet/etl/commit/65bdb37f7f463de90816e44283ca57f05225719e).

I don't really see how the use of std::async could so alter the compilation times. I have looked at the code, but I don't see anything that should cause so much havoc.

If someone has a clue, I'd be very to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a extreme speed difference. Under ideal circumstances that's not what should be expected.

The reason it takes longer time is that all data that needs to be handled during the compilation will grow in size. There will be a (slightly) larger symbol table, there will be a larger parse tree.

If you're running into a situation where all the data does not fit into memory you could suffer from swapping problems.

Comment: The build "only" takes about 4.5GB of my 12GB of RAM. There is no swap on this machine, so the compiler is killed when it goes out of memory, so I'm sure I'm not swapping.